# How do I disable i18next console warnings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I am using i18next with react app, however:

Logs like this on every re-render are really slowing down my application:

```
i18next::languageUtils: rejecting non-whitelisted language code: en
```

How do I disable them?

I have debug set to false.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can fix these errors one by one, for example, i18next  has an option for non-whitelisted language codes: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/6aa81cd22f5e7fe0989d6920471e8e32d173af8c/src/defaults.js#L12

There are other options too, can be helpful if you get other types of errors.

Answer (score 17):

Just change debug flag which goes in init function to false

```
i18n.init({
    resources,
    debug: false, // It should be false
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
  });
```